# extend PowerMockRunner and set public static fields

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

I need PowerMockRunner for a few of my tests and I use a 3rd party library which makes use of static public fields, which may not be null.

This works:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestSomething {    

    private ClassToTest fixture;    

    @Before
    public void setup() {    
        SomeStaticClass.variable = mock(Variable.class);            
        fixture = new ClassToTest();    
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {            
        System.out.println(SomeStaticClass.variable); // prints the mock
        assertNotNull(SomeStaticClass.variable); // passes
    }
}
```

So I decided I want to put the `SomeStaticClass.variable = mock(Variable.class);` part into an own PowerMockRunner like this:

```
public class MyRunner extends PowerMockRunner {
    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass) throws Exception {
        super(klass);
        SomeStaticClass.variable = mock(Variable.class);
    }
}
```

Now this does not work:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class TestSomethingWithMyRunner {

    private ClassToTest fixture;    

    @Before
    public void setup() {                
        fixture = new ClassToTest();    
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {            
        System.out.println(SomeStaticClass.variable); // prints null
        assertNotNull(SomeStaticClass.variable); // fails
    }
}
```

Overwriting run method does not work too:

```
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
    SomeStaticClass.variable = mock(Variable.class)
    super.run(notifier);
}
```

Where do I have to hook in, to set some static public fields before the tests are processed?

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely would not do that.

There is no point in saving a tiny bit of typing by introducing **super tight** coupling between that static field and your test code. And worse, this "relationship" would be very much hidden.

My suggestion: instead of putting things into a subclass of Runner - create a helper method that you can call in those test cases that need this setup.

You really do not want that other people looking at your tests can so easily overlook that you are using your **own** Runner that (under the cover) does such static settings. Such things need to be **explicit**. Unit tests should be written in a way that makes it super easy to understand all "preparations" going into each test case. Using a customer runner is achieving the "opposite" of that!

Besides: why are you using PowerMock in the first place? Either Mockito or EasyMock would do here.